# OCaml compiler reports a syntax error on "in" but interactive interpreter runs without flaws

Tags: ocaml

The following code runs without error on https://try.ocamlpro.com/

```
open Printf

let l = ref [] in
for i = 3 downto 0 do
  l := i :: !l
done;
List.iter (printf "%d " ) !l
```

but it triggers a syntax error when using `ocamlopt` or `ocamlc` compiler on Linux.

```
ocamlc array.ml -o array
```

```
let l = ref [] in
               ^^
Error: Syntax error
```

Comment: I just try your code (C/P) and it's working (I just have prefxes `printf` by `Printf.` but I guess that you have already open the module?

Comment: @X.VandeWoestyne, yes, I have in my script open Printf and
open Format

Comment: @X.VandeWoestyne Whenever I use an "in" it returns a syntax error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax error is probably hidden in the code that you did not include.
It seems probable that you have written

```
open Printf
let l = ref [] in
for i = 3 downto 0 do
  l := i :: !l
done;
List.iter (printf "%d " ) !l
```

which is a syntax error because a toplevel expression cannot follow a non-expression toplevel item. This is why the syntax error is on the `in`: only toplevel definitions (thus with no `in`) are allowed at this location.

This is why it is generally advised to use toplevel unit definition rather than expression:

```ml
open Printf
let () =
  let l = ref [] in
  for i = 3 downto 0 do
    l := i :: !l
  done;
  List.iter (printf "%d " ) !l
```

With this little change, you only have toplevel definitions and you don't need to memorize the rule for toplevel expressions.

Another simple option is to consider that all toplevel expression should be introduced by `;;`:

```ml
open Printf

;; let l = ref [] in
  for i = 3 downto 0 do
    l := i :: !l
  done;
  List.iter (printf "%d " ) !l
```